# ¿Cómo hacer que un puntero tipo char obtenga el valor de otro puntero tipo char? C++

Tags: c++

Tengo la siguiente clase en el fichero `clase.h`:

```
class Color {
private:
    char *color;
public:
    void setColor( char *color2 ); //Modifica el color
}
```

¿Cómo haría en el `clase.cc` para que `color` tenga el valor que tiene `color2`?
Me quedo en el siguiente paso, ya que no sé cómo hacerlo.

```
void Clase::setColor( char *color2 ) {

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En C++, un *puntero* es en realidad **un tipo completo**. Imaginemos que hubiera disponible un `operator typename( )` que nos devolviera el nombre de un tipo:

```
int a;
typename( a ); // => 'int'.

float b;
typename( b ); // => 'float'.
```

¿ Que pasaría si lo usamos con un puntero ?

```
char *c;
typename( c ); // => 'char *'.
```

Es decir, una variable *puntero* es, en realidad, del tipo *puntero a X*.

Vale, pues ahora, la cuestión es: ¿ Como asignamos un valor a una variable **del mismo tipo** ?

```
int a;
a = 10; // Ok. Por defecto, '10' es del tipo int.
```

La asignación es directa, sin complicaciones.

Ahora, veamos **dentro** de una función:

```
void mifuncion( int j ) {
  int h = j;
  ...
}
```

Ya vemos que **no hay cambios**; el tipo se indica en la lista de argumentos, y el compilador se asegura de que coincide al llamar a nuestra función:

```
myfuncion( 10 ); // => Ok.
myfuncion( 0.5f ); // => ERROR. Un float NO ES un int
```

Pues ya está todo; si el tipo es el mismo, **la asignación es directa**:

```
class Color{
  char *color;
public:
  void setColor( char *color2 ) {
    color = color2;
  }
};
```

Rápido, fácil, y sencillo :-)

**Nota**: En realidad, `C++` **si** tiene algo parecido al `typename( )`: El [operador `typeid( )`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid). No es exactamente igual, sino que nos devuelve una referencia a una instancia de `std::type_info`, **requiriendo** incluir `#include <typeinfo>`, y teniendo ciertas *cosillas* dependientes del compilador ... pero, en esencia, permitiría escribir expresiones **similares** a las expuestas:

```
int a;
std::cout << typeid( a ).name( ) << '\n'; // <-- 'i' ;

char *b;
std::cout << typeid( b ).name( ) << '\n'; // <-- 'pc' ;
```

Las asignaciones en `C++` pueden llegar a ser un tema complejo ... constructores, conversiones de tipos, precedencia de esas operaciones, ... **No** entro en detalles por no *desviarnos* demasiado de la pregunta :-)

Comment: cambia `typename` por `typeid`: https://wandbox.org/permlink/0uVsHVhSnfArWunK

Comment: @eferion No lo puse porque me parece que está *un pelín* mas allá del nivel del OP ... pero bueno :-)